# USING CASE AS PART OF JOIN ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, case

I have a query in Oracle SQL Developer to grab data from a raw table (all the data on the raw table are varchars) where I need to "clean" the data when I select it.  Have to use a CASE statement to get the store number because sometimes that data isn't in the STORENBR column but can be found in a substring of another column -

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN m.STORENBR = '0' AND (SUBSTR(m.SENDING_QMGR, 1, 5) = 'PDPOS')
        THEN TO_NUMBER((SUBSTR(m.SENDING_QMGR, 8, 4)))
    WHEN m.STORENBR = '0' AND (SUBSTR(m.SENDING_QMGR, 1, 8) = 'PROD_POS')
        THEN TO_NUMBER((SUBSTR(m.SENDING_QMGR, 9, 4)))
    ELSE TO_NUMBER(NVL(m.STORENBR, '0'))  
    END AS STORENBR, 
TO_NUMBER(NVL(m.CONTROLNBR,'0')) AS CONTROLNBR, 
TO_NUMBER(NVL(m.LINENBR,'0')) AS LINENBR,
TO_DATE(m.TRANDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS TRANDATE,
TO_NUMBER(NVL(m.NUMMISPRINTED,'0.00'),'99.99')  AS NUMMISPRINTED
FROM MISPRINTS_RAW m
WHERE TO_DATE(m.TRANDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') = '15-MAR-21'
ORDER BY m.STORENBR;
```

Now I need to also pull an account number from another table (TRANSACTIONS t - not a raw table, so I don't need any CASE or TO_NUMBER to pull data) but I need to join that table on STORENBR, CONTROLNBR, and LINENBR.  So how do I use that CASE statement as part of the join to JOIN m.STORENBR on t.STORENBR?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation -- perhaps along with a SQL/DB fiddle.

Comment: What about using a view or a subselect of the raw table, which provides the columns and hides the case statement. Use that view (or subselect) in the final join.

Answer (score 0):

Even if I am not sure about the data structure the following statement should be helpful.
The table with the raw data is "converted" in a subselect, so that a normal join is possible.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN m.storenbr = '0' 
                      AND ( Substr(m.sending_qmgr, 1, 5) = 'PDPOS' ) THEN 
                 To_number( 
                 ( Substr(m.sending_qmgr, 8, 4) )) 
                 WHEN m.storenbr = '0' 
                      AND ( Substr(m.sending_qmgr, 1, 8) = 'PROD_POS' ) THEN 
                 To_number(( Substr(m.sending_qmgr, 9, 4) )) 
                 ELSE To_number(Nvl(m.storenbr, '0')) 
               END                                              AS STORENBR, 
               To_number(Nvl(m.controlnbr, '0'))                AS CONTROLNBR, 
               To_number(Nvl(m.linenbr, '0'))                   AS LINENBR, 
               To_date(m.trandate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')                AS TRANDATE, 
               To_number(Nvl(m.nummisprinted, '0.00'), '99.99') AS NUMMISPRINTED 
        FROM   misprints_raw m) m1, 
       TRANSACTION t 
WHERE  t.storenbr = m1.storenbr 
       AND t.controlnbr = m1.controlnbr 
       AND t.linenbr = m1.linenbr 
       AND m1.trandate = DATE '2021-03-15' 
ORDER  BY m1.storenbr;
```

Comment: Thank you - I wasn't seeing how I could use the subselect.  This clears it up for me!

Comment: If the answer given resolved you question or even just pointed you to how to resolve it yourself then please accept the answer. Doing so helps future questioners with the same or similar issue resolve theirs.  Please do not just leave open a successfully answered question.

Comment: @dMika One issue here - where do I put t.ACCTNBR in the SELECT, which I need to pull from the Transactions table?

Comment: You can use `t.ACCTNBR` and any other column from `TRANSACTIONS` table as well as `m1`columns in the select list instead of the `*`.